# Dual wifi and wireless problem

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have both a wired and wireless connection (Ub14.04), and when I connect the wired my wifi internet stops working.
I have checked "Use this connection only for the resources on its network" checkbox. It is a static IP 192.168.1.1, mask=24, gateway=0.0.0.0, DNS server=10.0.0.10.

My routing tables are (2nd has the wired connection):

```
ed@master:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    
Use Iface
default         dsldevice.lan   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
ed@master:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

I don't really understand this stuff! Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same problem:
I put gateway=192.168.1.254, this did not fix it.
Originally I checked "Use this connection only for the resources on its network" checkbox for **IPv4**. Checking it for Ipv6 too, solved it!